# Почему я не могу использовать ссылку на метод и условие в качестве предиката в методе filtering()?

Tags: java, lambda

Разъясните, пожалуйста, одну вещь, которую я не понимаю.
Сейчас читаю книгу Modern Java, и не очень понятен один пункт.

```
Map<Type, List<Dish>> dishesByType = menu.stream().collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType,
            filtering(d->d.getCalories() > 500, toList())));
```

В данном коде в метод filtering я передаю условие, в виде лямбда выражения. Вопрос - почему я не могу передать туда вот такое условие - Dish::getCalories > 500?

```
@Data
public static class Dish {
    private final String name;
    private final boolean vegetarian;
    private final int calories;
    private final Type type;

    public Dish(String name, boolean vegetarian, int calories, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.vegetarian = vegetarian;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что "вот такое условие" сравнивает ссылку на метод и число `500`. Компилятор должен был Вам об этом сказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что предикат по определению -- функция,возвращающая булевое значение и в данном контексте принимающая аргумент с типом `Dish`.  Таким образом, в качестве ссылки на метод могли бы использоваться только:

- статический метод вида: `static boolean over500Calories(Dish dish)`: `filtering(MyClass::over500Calories)`
- метод в классе `Dish`: `class Dish { public boolean over500() { return calories > 500;}}`

При особом желании ссылку на метод можно было бы использовать
например при такой реализации `over500Calories`:

```java
private static boolean over500Calories(Dish dish) {
    return over(dish, Dish::getCalories, 500);
}

private static <T> boolean over(T obj, ToIntFunction<T> getter, int value) {
    return getter.applyAsInt(obj) > value;
}
```